How to find the mathematical function from list of plots
I would like to find the mathematical function that could approximately fit all of the following points :

x = [560, 387, 280, 231, 196, 168, 148, 136, 124, 112, 104, 101, 93, 88, 84, 80, 76]
y = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90]

coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, len(x) - 1)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)

But if I test this polynomial, I get wrong values :
x1 = []
y1 = [] 
for i in range(276, 570, 1):
    x1.append(i)
    y1.append(polynomial(i))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o')
plt.show()



Why do you want a polynomial of degree N-1 to fit N points? The first step of polynomial curve fitting is observing the data and picking the right degree of polynomial

You're extrapolating. Even lower-order polynomials can produce bad results outside of the range you used when generating the fits.

Based on the shape of your plot, you might be better off curve fitting with a function that better matches what you observe, such as 1 + exp(-x) in this case.

Degree 16 is a bit high.  Pick a smaller degree:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [560, 387, 280, 231, 196, 168, 148, 136, 124, 112, 104, 101, 93, 88, 84, 80, 76]
y = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90]

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

for degree in (2, 3, 4, 5):
    coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)
    polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)

    x1 = np.arange(76, 570, 1)
    y1 = [polynomial(i) for i in x1] 
    plt.plot(x1, y1, '-')

plt.legend('data deg2 deg3 deg4 deg5'.split())
plt.show()

Output:


Thank you Mark, I added some points manually between 300 and 500  to improve the result. I have a good curve with deg7

Following https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html
it is recommended to use
coefficients = Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg=degree)
for new coding. Instead of
coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)


Thanks you Thomas, I modified the code following your advice
